# Can i specify a color to be transparent

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a `UIImage`, the background of it is white. I want the background of this `UIImage` to be transparent to its parent view. Is this possible?

Comment: you have to use photo editing softwares to accomplish that. it cannot be done iphone(easily).

Comment: If you mean you want to set the background color of a view to transparent, try `[yourView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]`.

Answer (score 1):

One word answer- No. As robin said you have to use photo editing softwares to accomplish that. it cannot be done iphone(easily)..

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to suggest that it is easy, but you should take a look at CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors, which is described in the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide: Bitmap Images and Image Masks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify the transparency of a color from an image, but you could make a PNG image which has a transparency in the places you want it to be transparent.